# How to set SelectedColour Property for TabView using TabViewItemDataTemplate?

Tags: c#, xamarin, tabview

I am working on TabView control to create multiple tab page using "TabItemSource". In most of the sample provided in open source, the "TextColorSelected" property can be set in xct:TabViewItem. For my case, how can I set "TextColorSelected" property while using TabItemSource?

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:xct="clr-namespace:Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.UI.Views;assembly=Xamarin.CommunityToolkit"
         x:Class="MultiPosApp.Restaurant.Views.KitchenOrderTicketView"
         xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
         x:Name="KitchenOrderTicketVM"
         Title="Kitchen Order Ticket">

<xct:TabView  TabItemsSource="{Binding KitchenOrderCollection}" TabStripPlacement="Top" TabStripBackgroundColor="AliceBlue" TabStripHeight="50"  IsSwipeEnabled="False" TabIndicatorColor="Black"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIdx}">

    <xct:TabView.TabViewItemDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label Text="{Binding Location}" 
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                        TextColor="Black" 
                        FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </xct:TabView.TabViewItemDataTemplate>
      
    <xct:TabView.TabContentDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding TableOrderCollection}" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="3">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Frame BorderColor="LightGray" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="GhostWhite" HasShadow="True" CornerRadius="10">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                        <Label Text="TABLE " TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Label Text="{Binding Table.TableNum}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    

                                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding MenuOrderCollection}" Orientation="Vertical">
                                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                                    <Label Text="{Binding ItemQuantity}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="Center"/>
                                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MenuStatus}" IsEnabled="{Binding CheckboxEnabled}" HorizontalOptions="End">
                                                        <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                                            <prism:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChanged" Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ChkboxChangedCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=KitchenOrderTicketVM}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                                                        </CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                                    </CheckBox>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>

        </DataTemplate>
    </xct:TabView.TabContentDataTemplate>
</xct:TabView>
```

Comment: TabContentDataTemplate is for content of your tab items. Property TextColorSelected on TabViewItem and you need also to realize TabViewItemDataTemplate.

Comment: @Spawn so how am I going to define TextColorSelected property in TabViewItemDataTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to set the `TextColorSelected` property in `TabViewItemDataTemplate`.

For scenarios where you are not sure of the number of `TabViewItems`, you could try drawing the layout in code behind.

Something like:

```
public Page10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ....
        foreach (var item in tabview.TabItemsSource) //here the tabitemsource is a array of strings for test.
        {
            var tabViewItem = new TabViewItem
            {
     
                Text = (string)item,
                TextColor = Color.White,
                TextColorSelected = Color.Red,

            };
            var label = new Label
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Text = (string)item
            };
            tabViewItem.Content = label;
            tabview.TabItems.Add(tabViewItem);
        }
    }
```

define a `x:Name` for `TabView`:

```
<xct:TabView x:Name="tabview"  TabItemsSource="{Binding KitchenOrderCollection}" TabStripPlacement="Top" TabStripBackgroundColor="AliceBlue" TabStripHeight="50"  IsSwipeEnabled="False" TabIndicatorColor="Black"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIdx}">

         ...
</xct:TabView>
```